# How to un-ignore a file with git?

Tags: git

I added a file by mistake to `.git/info/exclude`
I removed it from the `.git/info/exclude`
but I can't get git to track it again

when I try to checkout the file I get a

> error: pathspec [filename] did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: check .gitignore in your directory

Comment: You can identify the pattern/reason that git forcing your file to be ignored. Just use `git check-ignore -v yourfile`

Answer (score 1):

try `git update-index` with assume-unchanged

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

the files are always assumed unchanged.
 want to track changes in these files again, use `--no-assume-unchanged`.

To get a list of files that are assume-unchanged run this:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]'
```

- `git ls-files -v` will print all files with their status.
- `grep '^[a-z]'` will filter files and select only assume unchanged

to undo all assume-unchanged that we have made then use : `git update-index --really-refresh`

more about [git-update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

Comment: git ls-files returns an empty list :(

Comment: Try this : git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD

Comment: what should I do with the output of ls-tree?

Comment: we can track files. so what exactly you have passed at  <file> in git update-index

Comment: I'm sorry @MAhipal I don't understand what I need to do with this. the problematic file is call settings.py